# android.view.InflateException Error inflating class com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView

Tags: java, android, inflate-exception, staggered-gridview

I am implementing the library provided by etsy on github for StaggeredGrid https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid . The error i am getting is InflationException for the layout activity_svg.xml

```
<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:item_margin="8dp"
app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count" />
```

android.view.InflationException Binary XML File Line#3 Error inflating class com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
As per previous answers related to the question i have checked the constructors :

```
 public StaggeredGridView(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public StaggeredGridView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public StaggeredGridView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
```

As per previous answer i have also checked whether the file lies in this library or not.
So what else can be the problem for InflationException ? Why is the class not getting inflated?

If you want me to add any more part of the code please comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom controls in your application then it should be specified using the full package in your layout XML, if only "yourcustomcontrol" is used it will throw this error. For example:

```
<yourcustomcontrol android:id="@+id/yourCustomControl1" /> will throw error.
<packageName.yourcustomcontrol android:id="@+id/yourCustomControl1" />
```

will work.
More about custom controls can be found at the android developers' homepage [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698407/232727).

Comment: I have mentioned in the code already the package name. AS you read in my mentioned question.